# Python: не работает метод

Tags: python

Первый метод проверяет пустая ли ячейка.
Второй - вызывает первый метод.

```
def empty(board, x, y, maxi):

    for x in range(maxi):
        for y in range(maxi):
            if board[x][y] == Game.EMPTY:
                print('Okey, thank you for your choice!')
                return True
            else:
                print('This cell is not empty!')
                return False

def take_input(board, player, maxi):
    while True:
        try:
            coorX = int(input("Row:"))
            coorY = int(input("Column:"))
            value = Game.empty(board, coorX, coorY, maxi)

        except ValueError:
            print("Should be an integer! Try again!")
            continue
        else:
            if coorX < 0 or coorX >= maxi and coorY < 0 or coorY >= maxi:
                print("Your input is incorrect! Look at you grid layout and try again!")
                continue
            elif (value == False):
                print("Your input is incorrect!")
                continue
            else:
                coorX = coorX-1
                coorY = coorY-1
                return coorX, coorY
```

Выводится следующее:

```
Row:1
Column:1
Okey, thank you for your choice!
['X', '', '', '', '', '']
['', '', '', '', '', '']
['', '', '', '', '', '']
['', '', '', '', '', '']
['', '', '', '', '', '']
['', '', '', '', '', '']

Turn for Y
Row:2
Column:2
This cell is not empty!
Your input is incorrect!
Row:
```

То есть первый раз функция работает правильно, а со второго раза она уже не распознает пустую ячейку. 
До метода empty все методы работали правильно.

Переписано:

```
coorX = x
coorY = y
for coorX in range(maxi): 
for coorY in range(maxi):
if board[coorX][coorY] == Game.EMPTY:
```

Answer (score 1):

В методе `empty` вы используете имена параметров `x` и `y`, в то время как в нём же вы используете `x` и `y` в качестве переменных цикла `for`:

```
def empty(board, x, y, maxi):    
    for x in range(maxi):  # переписываем переменную x
        for y in range(maxi):  # переписываем переменную y
```

Таким образом, первый вызов работает только потому, что он всегда устанавливает `board[0][0]`, а второй всегда будет пытаться его переписать.

Не очень понятно, зачем вы используете циклы в методе `empty`, ведь вам нужно только проверить одно значение в матрице, чтобы вернуть ответ.

P.S. В Python первый параметр методов принято называть `self`, вне зависимости от имени класса.

Comment: `coorX = xcoorY = y`
      `  for coorX in range(maxi):  # переписываем переменную x`
           ` for cootY in range(maxi): ` Перепесала, теперь этот метод на место X ставит Y

Comment: Скорее так, я обновила свой вопрос. В нем я вроде попыталась это исправить. Если я правильно вас поняла. Но в итоге ничего не изменилось.

Comment: Все. я поняла в чем ошибка. `(board[coorX-1][coorY-1] )`. вот что надо было сделать в моем случае! спасибо большое за помощь!